# Thrust : reduce_by_key is slower than expected

Tags: performance, cuda, parallel-processing, gpgpu, thrust

I have the following code :

```
   thrust::device_vector<int> unique_idxs(N);
   thrust::device_vector<int> sizes(N);
   thrust::pair<thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator, thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator> new_end = reduce_by_key(idxs.begin(), idxs.end(),thrust::make_constant_iterator(1),unique_idxs.begin(),sizes.begin());        
   int unique_elems=new_end.first-unique_idxs.begin();
   sizes.erase(new_end.second, sizes.end());
```

where `idxs` is a sorted device vector of indices, `unique_idxs` are the unique indices and `sizes` are the frequencies of each index.

Timing my program I found out that this operation takes a long time compared to other operations that handle the same or more amount of data... Is there any way to speed it up?

In fact, this part also causes NVIDIA Kernel Mode Crash when the size of `idxs` becomes more than 500k elements.

**EDIT**

I found this presentation about Thrust and I think I am doing exactly what it describes on page 38 which is supposed to run in milliseconds even for 10M points. I am testing my code on a GTX 480 as in the presentation.
http://thrust.googlecode.com/files/GTC%202010%20%28Part%202%29%20-%20Thrust%20By%20Example.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a terrible mistake! I was not timing my code properly and, as a result, I thought the delay was due to the reduction part while a transformation I was performing earlier was the culprit.